# Combine TestCaseAttribute and ValuesAttribute NUnit C#

Tags: c#, nunit, parametrized-testing

I need to do something like this:

```
[TestCase(1, 0, TestName = "Small values")]
[TestCase(int.MaxValue, 0, TestName = "Big precision value")]
[TestCase(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue - 1, TestName = "Big precision and scale values")]
public void Constructor_ThrowNoExceptions_OnCorrectArguments(int precision, int scale,
   [Values] bool onlyPositive)
{
   Action action = () => new NumberValidator(precision, scale, onlyPositive);
   action.Should().NotThrow();
}
```

I want to have `TestName` and two values from testcase and run them for values `onlyPositive`: `true` and `false`.

I have no idea how to do this because code above doesn't work.

I get *Method requires 3 arguments but TestCaseAttribute only supplied 2* `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException`.

If I put true or false in `TestCase`, `ValuesAttribute` just ignored and stops working.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply a `ValuesAttribute` on a paramenter, you must apply one on every parameter.
From the [documenation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/values.html):

> The `ValuesAttribute` is used to specify a set of values to be provided for an individual parameter of a parameterized test method. Since NUnit combines the data provided for each parameter into a set of test cases, **data must be provided for all parameters if it is provided for any of them.**

---

What you want can be achieved using a [`TestCaseSourceAttribute`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html).
That one allows to pass arguments in order to make variations of the test cases being returned.

The 3 number combination test cases will be run 2 times; one time with `onlyPositive` `true`, a second time with `false`.

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(GetTestCases), new object[] { true })]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(GetTestCases), new object[] { false })]
public void ConstructorThrowNoExceptionsOnCorrectArguments(
    int precision, int scale, bool onlyPositive
    )
{
    Action action = () => new NumberValidator(precision, scale, onlyPositive);
    action.Should().NotThrow();
}

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetTestCases(bool onlyPositive)
{
    yield return new TestCaseData(1, 0, onlyPositive)
        .SetName("Small values");

    yield return new TestCaseData(int.MaxValue, 0, onlyPositive)
        .SetName("Big precision value");

    yield return new TestCaseData(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue - 1, onlyPositive)
        .SetName("Big precision and scale values"); 
}
```